# VB.NET GridView Ignore Null Values in Footer Total

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataview

VB.net

```
Protected Sub monthlyReportsUK_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
   Dim rowTotal As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "webShopTotal").ToString)
   grdTotal = grdTotal + rowTotal
End If

If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
   Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblwebsVal"), Label)
   lbl.Text = "£" + grdTotal.ToString("##,0.00")
End If

End Sub
```

HTML:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="webShopTotal">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblamount" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("webShopTotal") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblwebsVal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

GridView

```
Month   Value
Jan     NULL
Feb     NULL
Mar     15.00
Apr     10.00
```

I want to be able to sum the values:

```
   Month   Value
    Jan     NULL
    Feb     NULL
    Mar     15.00
    Apr     10.00
   Total    25.00
```

However, I am getting the error `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.`

Is there any way I can add the total in the footer ignoring NULL values?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Protected Sub monthlyReportsUK_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then    
 If DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "webShopTotal").ToString IsNot Nothing AndAlso DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "webShopTotal").ToString IsNot DbNull.Value Then
   Dim rowTotal As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "webShopTotal").ToString)
   grdTotal = grdTotal + rowTotal
 End Id
End If

If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
   Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("lblwebsVal"), Label)
   lbl.Text = "£" + grdTotal.ToString("##,0.00")
End If

End Sub
```

**Edit**

First, you should always use [System.Decimal.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) instead of Convert.ToDecimal()

```
Dim result  = 0
Dim rowTotal As Decimal = Decimal.TryParse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "webShopTotal").ToString), out result)
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i get the error `Input string was not in a correct format. `

Comment: refering to `Dim rowTotal As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "webShopTotal").ToString`

Comment: Use Decimal.TryParse(value, out number) instead of Convert.ToDecimal